# I'm having trouble making this vertical navbar into horizontal one in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">I/H</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#work">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#connect">Connect!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I would like to delete the button and turn this bad boy into a horizontal navbar using CSS, but im having trouble with that. Any suggestions? after looking at literally hundreds of different ways to do this, I cant figure it out. If I leave the button on there, every time I click it and open the drop down menu, my social media icons that reside directly below move into a different location. So, instead of trying to mess with that, I have decided to remove the button and make this vertical list into a horizontal one, but when I try it's not working.

It's been solved!

Comment: have you included the bootstrap css...?

Comment: Yeah, the Bootstrap CSS is where I'm trying to do this in. I have a Bootstrap CSS And a Font awesome CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use Bootstrap's `navbar-expand` class...

https://www.codeply.com/go/fDfvWpQh71

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">I/H</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#work">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#connect">Connect!</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'll try this out, Thank you.

Comment: You're a genius! I really appreciate your help.